# how to adjust height for dynamic content without using specific classes in masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

i was seeing this link at codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yhteF.

i found that they have used specific classes for adjusting height, such as `.item.h2`, `.item.h3` etc. what if my content is dynamic and it increase or decreases? because these a classes with specific height, how do i adjust dynamic content in it? I also tried to `h2` and `h3` classes, but then also it didnot adjust. pls tell what am i missing.

Comment: put your code for a faster answer

Comment: the code is in this link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yhteF

Comment: that is an example, what is your code that does not work ?

Comment: @florin, just add content more than the height of anymenu, and thats my problem

Answer (score 0):

from your last comment i understand that you want that each item to have a height depending on its content

if this is the case , remove `height:` from `.masonry .item {`